# What's the best practice for debounce on search changes and instant fetch on page changes with useState and useEffect in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I'm having two state variables, `page` and `search`, and want to refetch data every time one of these are changed,

For search change I want to do debounce, and for page changes need to fetch instantly.

```
const [page, setPage] = useState()
const [search, setSearch] = useState();

const fetch = () => {
   axios.get("", {search, page}) // nvm the syntax
}

useEffect(()=>{
   const timer = setTimeout(()=>{ fetch() }, 3000)

   return () => { clearTimeout(timer) }
}, [search])

useEffect(()=>{
   fetch();
}, [page])
```

Unfortunately I'm getting eslint exhaustive deps warning here, if I fix these warnings, then fetch is called twice on change, could you please explain what's the correct way/best practice to tackle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a `useDebouncedValue` -

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React

function useDebouncedValue(value, delay) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(value)
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const t = setTimeout(setState, delay, value)
      return () => { clearTimeout(t) }
    },
    [value, delay]
  )
  return state
}

function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState("hello")
  const debouncedFoo = useDebouncedValue(foo, 1000)
  return <div>
    <input onChange={e => setFoo(e.target.value)} value={foo} />
    debounced: {debouncedFoo}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Using it in your component might look something like this -

```js
const [page, setPage] = useState()
const [search, setSearch] = useState()
const debouncedSearch = useDebouncedValue(search, 3000)

useEffect(
  () => {
    axios
      .get("", {search: debouncedSearch, page})
      .then(setResults)
      .catch(console.error)
  },
  [page, debouncedSearch])
)
```

Comment: why also first call to `clearTimeout(timer.current)`?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava wups, I left that line in after changing the implementation. Thanks for catching that.